# How to deal with extremely unbalance data set like JFT-300M in this paper"Revisiting Unreasonable Effectiveness of Data in Deep Learning Era"?

Tags: deep-learning

In this paper, "Revisiting Unreasonable Effectiveness of Data in Deep Learning Era", the author using a new data set named **JFT-300M** to explore the influence of big data for deep learning.The author describe the data set has a heavily long-tailed, In fact, the tail is so heavy that have more than 3K categories with less than 100 images each and approximately 2K categories with less than 20 images per category.At conclusion:Our data has quite a long tail and yet the representation learning seems to work. **This long-tail does not seem to adversely affect the
stochastic training of ConvNets** (training still converges).I want to know the reason behind this, or the author use other technology?

Answer (score 0):

As usually there are many ways, I think a proper [data augmentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36144993/data-augmentation-techniques-for-small-image-datasets) is always a good idea.

Also, regarding the 2000+ classes, you may find [hierarchical softmax](http://building-babylon.net/2017/08/01/hierarchical-softmax/) idea useful.